# mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, aws

I cannot re-mount an AWS EBS drive to a Ubuntu instance. I'm not sure if this is a Ubuntu thing or Amazon Web Services. It's not a bootable drive.

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /data

mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
```

I originally mounted it following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

I rebooted, and the mount was missing.

I tried

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/xvdf

/dev/xvdf: clean, 17665/1073741824 files, 233339937/4294967296 blocks

e2fsck also output the same.
```

I thought maybe the fstab was corrupted so I returned it to original state and then rebooted, but I still cannot mount the drive.

**EDIT:**

I ran the following, and it shows an error. The current block size is 4096 according to `sudo stat -f /dev/xvde`

```
sudo e2fsck -c /dev/xvde
badblocks: Value too large for defined data type invalid end block 

(4294967296): must be 32-bit value
/dev/xvde: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/xvde: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/xvde: 17666/1073741824 files (15.2% non-contiguous), 233339938/4294967296 blocks
```